# Javascript iPad, iPhone and Android - How to get page full width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, iphone, ipad

I am wondering how to get the page width/height and not the viewport's width and height.
I tried innerWidth/Height and outerWidth/height.

In order to get the complete width/height of the screen so i need to + the inner with the outer? Or os there some other way to get the complete page width/height for the 3 devices i mentioned in my title.

Comment: Tried `$(document).width()` ?

Comment: If `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">` is specified, then the width/height will be resized. If not, $(document).width() should work.

Comment: This is the current viewport i am using: "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />" So from what i understand i cannot get width from document or window. So is there any other work around to get the correct width/height for both iPad/iPhone and Android devices? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can detect screensize and the useable are of the screen by using the “screen” object.

screen.height - shows the height of the screen
screen.width - shows the width of the screen.
screen.availHeight - shows height but removes the interface height like taskbar, and browser menu etc.
screen.availWidth - same as above,instead gives available width.

Comment: @kernel, None of those are working. They just return the screen size. Not the size of the page. I need the complete width/height of the page not the device. I need a solution for the 3 devices mentioned.

Thank you.

Comment: @DannieHansen In that case, try document.body.scrollWidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if  you're using iphone or ipad's UIWebView, you can use this Javascript Code;

```
NSLog(@"%@",[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth;"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]);
```

your scroll size is your full page size.

i dont have any idea about android or etc.

Comment: I will test this out in a moment. But that means that "document.body.scrollWidth" is the width of the screen? If so then you're the guy with the answer :) Thanks

Comment: "document.body.scrollWidth" returns you size of UIWebView's content.